# How to make part of the caption italic?

Tags: captions, italic, emphasis

I just want a few words in my caption to be italic, not the entire caption. I have seen other questions on here about making part of a figure/table caption italic, but all solutions I saw were just using the `\textit{}` command. I have of course tried this but it will not work for me. `\emph{}` also does not work. However I can get bold text with `\textbf{}`, so this is strange to me.

This is the code I use:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Figures/myfigure.png}
    \caption[Caption for in TOC.]{Caption for in TOC. This would be my longer caption that appears 
    in my actual document. I would like some words to be \textit{italic, such as this part.} However, 
    it just comes out as \emph{normal text}. Obviously, \textbf{bold text works just fine}.}
    \label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}
```

This is the output that I get:

[image]

Additional info:

I am using this caption package: `\usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=centerlast]{caption}`

I am also using the `tudelft-report.cls` class.
I have a feeling I need to change something here, but as I am far from being a LaTeX guru I have no idea how to fix this. The class is available here: https://github.com/praseodym/tudelft-report-latex/blob/master/tudelft-report.cls.

I am using the pdfLaTeX compiler.

Many thanks in advance! :)

---

Edit: I did my best to make a MWE. I obviously removed some preambles for clarity but I left everything in that might have something to do with the caption (I think).

```
\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{pdfcolmk}{Nothing to fix}
\documentclass[table]{tudelft-report}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{changes}

%%%%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   % for accent letters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % also for accent letters
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=centerlast]{caption} % editing caption layout
\usepackage{wrapfig}    % for wrapping text around figures
\usepackage{graphicx}   % something with figures


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Figures/myfigure.png}
    \caption[Caption for in TOC.]{Caption for in TOC. This would be my longer caption that appears 
    in my actual document. I would like some words to be \textit{italic, such as this part.} However, 
    it just comes out as \emph{normal text}. Obviously, \textbf{bold text works just fine}.}
    \label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please post a complete MWE, that shows which class and packages you are using? It might be as simple, that your used font is not available in italics, but to confirm, we would need to see your smalles preamble, that still shows the issue.

Comment: I can confirm  that there's no problem with the  standard `report` class.  Where is  tudelt-report available?

Comment: Hi, the class is available here: https://github.com/praseodym/tudelft-report-latex/blob/master/tudelft-report.cls. I am using the pdfLaTeX compiler by the way, I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: I think you could use the `filecontents` environment to make an MWE, see `texdoc latex2e`

Comment: @quantumgirl If I take your MWE and the class file you refer to, the italic text is italic with my installation. Can you check the MWE on your machine again, please?

Comment: @TobiBS It still does not work for me, hmm... Maybe I have loaded an unnecessary package. I will try to look at it a little more in depth. Thanks for your answers though!

Comment: @quantumgirl Did you really copy the code from above (your MWE) and use the class (as in the git)? And can you post your *.log file?

Comment: @TobiBS yes, I ran the MWE exactly as I wrote it here and it doesn't work.

Comment: @quantumgirl and would you be able to post your log file? Have a look for the word `instead` and copy the lines around it. What compiler are you using (pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX)?

Comment: @TobiBS I'm still figuring out an easy way to post the logfile haha. I have multiple instances for the word ```instead```. I am using the pdfLaTeX compiler.

Comment: I think you can view it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NgzAjazU01d5Xz_RmWxLqgR6a_eeokNn/view

Comment: @TobiBS hello, sorry to bother you, do you have any idea what might be the issue? :) I have tried it once more and I found out I can italicize text in my caption, but only if it's already bold. I have no idea what that is about... Captions are in the same font as my normal text and italics work in normal text.

Comment: @quantumgirl sorry, you didn't mention me with the @, so I didn't receive a ping and hence didn't look into that issue. I will have a further look in your log.

Comment: @quantumgirl as I suspected, your LaTeX compiler has the issue of not finding the respective font, this is indicated by the line `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/futs/el/it' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/futs/el/n' instead on input line 22.` in the log, which says your `*/it` font (the italic shape) is replaced by th `*/n` normal shape. However I have no idea what went wrong, because in my installation the MWE compiles just fine, hence I would try to reinstall the respective font package.

Comment: @TobiBS No worries, thanks for all the effort. I find it strange because I can put italic text in my body text without any problems, as far as I know the fonts are the same. Anyway, thanks again!